# Selecting columns of Dataframe in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If you want to select the first column of a dataframe this can be done:

```scala
df.select(df.columns(0))
```

`df.columns(0)` returns a string, so by giving the name of the column, the select is able to get the column correctly.

Now, suppose I want to select the first 3 columns of the dataset, this is what I would intuitively do:

```scala
df.select(df.columns.split(0,3):_*)
```

The `_*` operator would pass the array of strings as a varag to my understanding, and it would be the same as passing `(df.column(1), df.column(2), df.column(3))` to the select statement. However this doesn't work and it is necessary to do this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
df.select(sf.columns.split(0,3).map(i => col(i)):_*))
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I think in the question you meant `slice` instead of `split`.

And as for your question,
`df.columns.slice(0,3):_*` is meant to be passed to functions with *-parameters (*varargs*), i.e. if you call `select(columns:_*)` then there must be a function defined with *varargs*, e.g. `def select(cols: String*)`.

But there can only be one such function defined - no overloading here is possible.
Example on why it's not possible to define two different functions with same *vararg*-parameter declaration:

```scala
def select(cols: String*): String = "string"
select() // returns "string"
def select(cols: Column*): Int = 3
select() // now returns 3
```

And in Spark, that one function is defined not for `String`s but for `Column`s:

```scala
def select(cols: Column*)
```

For `String`s, the method is declared like this:

```scala
def select(col: String, cols: String*)
```

I suggest you to stick to `Column`s, like you do now, but with some syntax sugar:

```scala
df.select(df.columns.slice(0,3).map(col):_*))
```

Or if there's a need to pass column names as `String`s, then you can use `selectExpr`:

```scala
df.selectExpr(df.columns.slice(0,3):_*)
```